# Basic Question on input to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have installed PostgreSQL on a Windows XP laptop so I can learn about using PostgreSQL. My problem is that the PostgreSQL tutorial starts of with the instruction

To create a new database, in this example named mydb, you use the following command:

$ createdb mydb

My problem is that it doesn't tell me how/where to input the command.  I have found access to an SQL Shell but it doesn't perform as expected.

What is the 'proper' way to input commands?

No GUI ?

Comment: Should I be using pgAdminIII ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createdb` is a commandline tool which should be run in a Windows commandline window ("Start -> Run -> "cmd.exe"). You have to have PostgreSQL's `bin` directory in the windows `PATH` in order for this to work without supplying the full program path.

As an alternative you can run SQL statements using the program `psql` (which is also a command line program).  You probably also have a start menu entry in the PostgreSQL folder name "SQL Shell" (or something similar) which starts `psql` directly.

A list of GUI tools (apart from pgAdmin) is available in the [Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools).

Comment: pgAdminIII is the answer to my question. I have found a tutorial that explains its functions. I cant post this as an answer yet though :)

Comment: I would upvote your answer a_horse_with_no_name but I dont have the rep yet. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I have accepted the answer given realising that there is no one right answer. The command line options will all work but having been used to do everything with a GUI, the pgAdminIII option suits me better.